# Extract play-services-ads jar from google-play-services 6.5+

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

*Question*:
How to extract `play-services-ads.jar` from `google-play-services.jar` ?

*Background*:
Since last update of google play services we may not include whole lib in our project when we need only one part of it [source](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html). The problem is that i cant add `google-play-services.jar` as library dependency in my project, it can be done only as file dependency. So i need somehow add only `play-services-ads.jar`, not the whole `google-play-services.jar` to avoid library method limit 65,536.

Comment: this is only supported in android studio. if for some reason you are still using eclipse there is no way to do what you want

Answer (score 0):

Using Android Studio, you can take advantage of the split Google Play Services libraries, ensuring you only include the part of Google Play Services necessary for what you need.

In your case, you will need to include the following AARs from AndroidSDK\extras\google\m2repository:
* com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:6.5.87
* com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.87

And the following AARs from AndroidSDK\extras\android\m2repository:
* com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3

Note that these are AARs and not JARs.